# How can I get the Command, Option, and Control keys to work properly using QuickSynergy and two Mac OS X Lion machines?

Tags: osx-lion, synergy

I have two Macs, a MacBook Pro (server) and a Mac Mini (client).  Is there a trick in getting the Command, Option, and Control key presses to get passed through to the client machine?  It doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](http://synergy-foss.org/tracker/issues/57) that is scheduled to be fixed in 1.4.9.